# Making an external API call from Javascript.

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Am I allowed to make an API call directly from Javascript to an external API ( in my case http://isbndb.com/docs/api/20-structure.html ) using the XMLHttpRequest object? If not how do I go about fetching data from this source? Do I have to add a PHP back end which makes the API call and then returns data to the front end JS? Is there any other way to fetch data without the need for back end code? I did some research online and found that this is possible in jQuery if the data format is JSON. But how do I do this with XML data?

Comment: You can't simply access to external domain resource via javascript unless jsonp way is provided. There are several workarounds such as backend coding just like you are thinking, or using proxy http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery's ajax method, you can pass it as a parameter a dataType, it can be json, xml, html or script. When it is set to xml in your success callback's first parameter will be XML from the server as a XML document you can work with